# Magento 2 coupon code : DIscount maximum up to x amount

Tags: coupon

i want to create coupon code in magneto something like below
1:discount 1% of sub-total up to a maximum of Rs. 300

i can not find any such way to do via magento backend

[image]

Comment: Please check and update me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Go Marketing -> Promotions -> Cart Price Rules -> Add New Rule**
>
> **Check Screen-shot here**

[image]
[image]

> After save above use **USER12** code and Run Magento command

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: could you please explain, how your solution prevent maximum amount validation ? creating new cart rule require setup upgrade ?

Comment: By creating coupon using above settings. You can used this coupon code when subtotal amount is equal to or Grater then 300. If amount is less than so coupon code is not works. And Setup upgrade is required some time.

Answer (score 0):

Install this extension, it is working to set maximum discount limit.

```
https://www.magepsycho.com/magento2-discount-limiter.html
```